# Sending Big files using Restbed http client

Tags: restbed

I am using restbed for http client in my c++ application and want to POST files which are in excess of 50 MB to a server. Is there any way to accomplish it.

Thanks

Comment: This may in fact be tricky (memory hog) with the current client functionality.  Please raise a feature request on the GitHub issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a look into [Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

You will find an example [here](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/documentation/example/TRANSFER_ENCODING_REQUEST.md).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I Can receive a chunked data stream on my rest server, but can not send a big file using the current api http::sync or http:async.

Comment: Will have this feature rolled out with the coming 4.5 release.